# Cascades BlackBerry. Click Control behind other

Tags: blackberry-cascades

We have an image `ImageButton` covered by a `Label`.

Is it possible to click on the `ImageButton` underneath the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found it

```
touchPropagationMode: TouchPropagationMode.PassThrough
        focusPolicy: FocusPolicy.None
```

Answer (score 0):

well the obvious think is to use transparent control on top of that. But in my opinion it is not clean way.